# What is the 'rate limit' exceeded of SoftLayer API endpoint?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I just met the `rate limit` exceeded error when send an API request. Its rate was about 1 per second. The service is `SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata`.

So do anyone know the SoftLayer's `rate limit` strategy? Such as the number of limits, the scope of limit(the same IP or the same account, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

the limit is 50 request for second for each user. The SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata service does not need an specific user so when you use this service I recommend do not exceed 50 request for second in your account.

Comment: Thank you. So it limits the account, not the user belonged to the account.

Comment: And how about to limit the rate limit to ip especially the resource service which requests from SL resource(such as virtual guests).

Comment: there is no limit for iP